# Changing Opacity With Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive, opacity

> <rant>Yes, I know this would be easier to implement in WPF.  I hear that a lot.  Sadly, It is not possible.
>   </rant>

I am writing a WinForms app, and I need to "fade" a Control in & out.  Transparency is all but impossible in WinForms, so I am trying to use opacity: the idea is to change the Alpha channel of each child control's ForeColor property over a period of time.  This seems like a perfect time to work on my Reactive Extensions!

My possible solution is:

```
private void FadeOut()
{
   // our list of values for the alpha channel (255 to 0)
   var range = Enumerable.Range(0,256).Reverse().ToList();

   // how long between each setting of the alpha (huge value for example only)
   var delay = Timespan.FromSeconds(0.5);

   // our "trigger" sequence, every half second
   Observable.Interval(delay)
        // paired with the values from the range - we just keep the range
          .Zip(range, (lhs, rhs) => rhs)
        // make OnNext changes on the UI thread
          .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
        // do this every time a value is rec'd from the sequence
          .Subscribe(
              // set the alpha value
              onNext:ChangeAlphaValues, 
              // when we're done, really hide the control
              onCompleted: () => Visible = false, 
              // good citizenry
              onError: FailGracefully);
}

// no need to iterate the controls more than once - store them here
private IEnumerable<Control> _controls;

private void ChangeAlphaValues(int alpha)
{
    // get all the controls (via an extension method)
    var controls = _controls ?? this.GetAllChildControls(typeof (Control));

    // iterate all controls and change the alpha
    foreach (var control in controls)
       control.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(alpha, control.ForeColor);
}
```

... which looks impressive, but it doesn't work. The really impressive part is that it doesn't work in *two ways*!  Gonna get a "Far Exceed" on my next performance review if I keep this up.  :-)

1. (Not really the Rx part of the problem) The alpha values don't actually seem to make any difference.  Despite setting the values, the display looks the same.
2. If I close the window before the sequence is complete, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Reactive.Core.dll
>   Additional information: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

I assume this is where a cancellation token would come in handy - but I have no idea how to implement it.

### I need guidance on:

How to close the window gracefully (i.e. without throwing an error) if the sequence is still running, and how to get the alpha values for the colors to actually *display* after they're changed.

### ... or maybe this is the wrong approach altogether.

I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: `I am writing a WinForms app, and I need to "fade" a Control in & out` - use WPF. winforms doesn't support animations. You can achieve this in WPF with a single line of XAML.

Comment: `Sadly, It is not possible` - then forget trying to introduce animations or any other rich UI features on winforms. Spend your time creating battleship gray, boring UIs, which  is  what winforms is about.

Comment: So, you're not completely open to other suggestions. ;) I'm curious why it's not possible. You can use `ElementHost` to put WPF controls in WinForms. Is that possible for you?

Comment: Have you tried checking for `Control.IsHandleCreated && ! Control.IsDisposed`?

Comment: @HighCore `which is what winforms is about`  ... sigh.  Yes, I know.  Stop poking the bear.  ;-)

Comment: @CoderDennis Yes, it's possible, but ElementHost has its own bucket of problems (black background, anyone?) that I'd like to avoid (if possible).

Comment: @Aron no, and I'm not sure *where* I'd perform that check.

Comment: @CoderDennis ... also, wouldn't I still have the same problem fading the ElementHost itself?

Comment: @ScottSEA you should perform that check before you change the opacity, EACH time you change the opacity.

Comment: @Aron - ah. gotcha.  Any clue on how to actually make the opacity change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help you with the WinForms transparency part.  Maybe you should split the question in two.

But for the Rx part, you just need to cancel your subscription when the window is closed.  `Subscribe` returns a `IDisposable`.  You should dispose of it in your `Closed` event.

And, since I assume this fade animation might be invoked multiple times before the window is closed, we can make use of an Rx helper `SerialDisposable`.

Finally, `Interval` actually returns a count.  We can use that to simplify your observable by just calculating the desired alpha.

```
private SerialDisposable _fadeAnimation = new SerialDisposable();

private void FadeOut()
{
    // how long between each setting of the alpha (huge value for example only)
    var delay = Timespan.FromSeconds(0.5);

    _fadeAnimation.Disposable = Observable
        .Interval(delay)
        // 256 animation steps
        .Take(256)
        // calculate alpha
        .Select(i => 255 - i)
        .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
        .Subscribe(
            // set the alpha value
            onNext:ChangeAlphaValues, 
            // when we're done, really hide the control
            onCompleted: () => Visible = false, 
            // good citizenry
            onError: FailGracefully);
}

private void Form1_Closed()
{
    _fadeAnimation.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You nailed the Rx part.  I had to create an `EventHandler` for the `Dispose` event (because it's a control, not a form) and put the `_fadeAnimation.Dispose()` there - but apples/apples.  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `SerialDisposable` be better in this case? If `FadeOut` were to be triggered again before the first one finished, the first subscription would not be disposed of.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, I would use `Observable.Generate(255, x => x >= 0, x => x - 1, x => x, x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))` as your base observable.

Comment: @paulpdaniels yes you are right. I thought that is what MultipleAssignmentDisposable did, but I guess it doesn't.